# How to Calculate Text Size Prior to Creating a CustomCell

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm creating a CustomCell that contains a `UILabel`, by default the `UILabel` will have two lines of text with wrap around enabled, but there are occasions when the text will require three lines.

The font type and size is fixed and cannot be changed, and I trying to identify a way of calculating the length of the `NSString`/`UILabel` prior to creating the `UITableView`/`CustomCell` so that the cell height can be set correctly. The text that will be displayed will be made up of a number of different words e.g. '*Your name is XXXXX XXXXX and your birthday is..*' and the XXXXXXX is the element that is variable.

Hopefully this makes sense, one idea I have considered is creating a method that contains a `UILabel` that is never displayed and populating it with the required text and then checking if 2 or 3 lines are used, but not sure how to do this.

Is there a more elegant method of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `NSString`s `sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode:` is the method you are looking for. This returns a `CGSize` which you can get the height of to determine your cell's height (and set the label's frame to the correct size obviously).

Note: you should pass a `CGSize` parameter in to the `constrainedToSize:` part that is a larger height than what you intend it to be but the correct maximum width of the label

Answer (score 1):

There are several UIKit functions for calculating with size of a string with various linebreak modes and fonts.  See [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

In particular `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` may be useful for this.